# Convert numeric string from file to exit code in shell

Tags: shell, awk, users

I'd like to grep /etc/password for a username and return the last two digits of a user-id number as the return code.

This is because I have an application whose main way of interacting with other programs is something like `integer_variable = run("some command")` which picks up the byte value of the exit code of the command.

I can do this using something like the following command

```
perl -n -e 'exit $1%100 if /^username:x:(\d+):/' /etc/passwd
```

Is there an equivalent using `awk` or some other standard utility?

Comment: @terdon: I agree it's unusual, but I have several Unix systems that lack it. For example, I have Xenix in a box somewhere. Some minimal Linux distros omitted it too.

Comment: Really? Actual Linux distros? Not embedded or busybox based systems? Wow, fair enough then, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id=$( getent passwd $username | cut -d: -f3 | sed 's/.*\(..\)$/\1/' )
```

with awk

```
awk -v u=$username -F: '$1 == u {exit $3%100}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "some other standard utility"? If you want a shell script to return arbitrary exit statuses, you can pass any value to the shell builtin `exit`:

```
exit `awk -F: $USER '{print $2}' /etc/passwd`
```

(or just `exit 35`, etc.)

That lets you transform output into an exit status, even for programs that do not have an `exit` operation like `perl` and `awk` do. But keep in mind that the Unix convention is for successful programs to return `0`, so you'll get some weird behavior if you run your special program from the commandline (etc.)

Comment: By standard utility I meant anything that is commonly available from the usual shells (sh, bash, ksh, csh ...) on Linux and Unix (both modern and ancient). On some Unix systems perl may not be installed as standard. Thanks for the tip re `exit`.

Comment: I see; I was counting `perl` among the standard options, hence the "why not just use perl" confusion.